# using JOIN in mysqli only return result from one table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to print the result of joining 2 tables using mysqli. but everytime i try to do it, it only return the result from one table while the table that it's joining doesn't return any result

below is the code that show the data into a table

```html
    foreach($db->showdata() as $x) {
         
          if($x['role_id'] == 1 || $x['role_id'] == 2) continue;
          $id = $x['user_id'];
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $x['user_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $x['first_name'] ." ". $x['last_name']. "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $x['nilai_tugas'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $x['nilai_uts'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $x['nilai_uas'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
                    }
```

while this one is the showdata() function it called

```html
function showdata(){
$data = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN grade ON(user.user_id = grade.user_id) IS NOT NULL;");
while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
  $hasil[] = $d;
}
return $hasil;
}
```

The structure of the table is

> User: user_id, first_name, last_name and other column that's irrelevant for this part
>
> Grade: user_id, nilai_tugas, nilai_uts, nilai_uas

when I run the code it return

> Notice: Undefined index: nilai_tugas
>   Notice: Undefined index: nilai_uts
>   Notice: Undefined index: nilai_uas

which is from the grade table, but the data from the user table do go through and show up in the page.
[The page result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc29G.png)

When I run the query in mysql it does return all the data I requested but it doesn't seem to return the data when in the function.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** I tried to move the select query into the same page and it work, it just don't work when I use return from function(which is mandatory).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try be more explicit in selecting your columns?

```
mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT user.columnname, grade.columnname FROM user LEFT OUTER JOIN grade ON(user.user_id = grade.user_id) IS NOT NULL;");
```

And are you sure the column in users is called user_id? Because the result set has the columnname studentID.

Comment: I added grade but nothing change

Comment: do you get a result if you leave of the IS NOT NULL part?

Comment: It still show the same result as before even if IS NOT NULL is there or not.

Comment: SELECT users.*, grades.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN grades ON users.id = grades.user_id
ORDER BY user.user_name;


I don't think you need the parenthesis after the ON clause and a left join instead of left outer join.

See this example:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: tried that too, still doesn't work at all. I'm starting to lean towards moving the code to the PHP file that show the data directly instead of using a function even though it may be a security issue(and spaghetti)

Comment: Interesting, i'm out of options too, sorry i can't help. Btw forget the outer join remark. Apparently that's perfectly fine: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Are you sure you column in the users table is called user_id and not studentID? Because your result set says studentID

Comment: @MartijnvanderBruggen It's not a result set, it's html. Also, if that column name was wrong, it would produce a notice just like the others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully know what happened, so I tried reinstalling xampp and it finally start working, the problem might be located in mysql config file(not the first time this happen to me).